# Transfer specific data from 1 datatable to another error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, row

How can I transfer the contents of one of my Datatable to a new Datatable? I am filtering out the contents of my Datatable as the filtering would work when I check on certain checkboxes. So what I did was to do this:

```
//dt & dt2 are Datatables, dt has all of the data and dt2 is a blank Datatable
string fieldcheck=  "2"
for (var f = 0; f < dt.Rows.Count; f++ )
{
    if (dt.Rows[f]["nameID"].ToString() == fieldcheck)
    {
        dt2.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[f]);
    }
}
```

But an error is saying that the row already belongs to another table. How can I transfer the specific row to the empty Datatable?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add a `DataRow` to a `DataTable` that belongs to another `DataTable`. Note that every row reference it's table via [`Table` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You either have to add them manually by copying all fields or use [`DataTable.ImportRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx):

```
dt2.ImportRow(dt.Rows[f]);
```

Another approach for your requirement is using `Linq-To-DataTable` which can simplify your code:

```
var matchingRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == fieldcheck)
DataTable dt2 = matchingRows.Any() ? matchingRows.CopyToDataTable() : dt.Clone();
```

Note that `CopyToDataTable`  throws an exception if there is no matching row. That's why i've used the conditional operator and `DataTable.Clone` as fallback value which creates an empty table with the same schema.

Comment: `CopyToDataTable` gives error when resultant collection do not return anything.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: good catch, i've edited the answer accodingly.